# Let $V$ be as vector space over a field $F$ and let $α, β, γ ∈ \operatorname{End}(V )$ satisfy $αβ = σ_1 = αγ$. Show that $βγ \neq γβ$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I need some help with this problem please:

Let $V$ be as vector space over a field $F$ and let $α, β, γ ∈
\operatorname{End}(V )$ satisfy $αβ = σ_1 = αγ$. Show that $βγ \neq γβ$.

$σ_1$ is the identity function and $\operatorname{End}(V )$ the endomorphism of $V$.

I think this problem is wrong for if we take $β=γ$ that is not true, but if someone have an idea it will be appreciated.
Thanks.

This is an exercise from the book: The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Should Know by Golan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably means that $\beta\gamma \ne \gamma\beta$ provided that $\beta \ne \gamma$.  Note that if $\beta\gamma = \gamma\beta$ we have
$$
\beta = \sigma_1\beta = \alpha\gamma\beta = \alpha\beta\gamma = \sigma_1\gamma = \gamma
$$

Comment: I see, thanks a lot